# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' in django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, anaconda

I have anaconda python 3.7 installed on my system. I am creating a Django project called learning log in a virtual environment(active at the time when the problem appeared) in G drive on my computer. I have defined and migrated the entry model but when I try to register entry with the admin site through file admin.py in the project folder with the following code ...

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Topic

# Register your models here
admin.site.register(Topic)
```

... and try to run it in my spyder editor it shows: 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-installing it with

```
pip install django
```

in your virtualenv?

Comment: i did.. it says requirement already satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pip installing, you might have to conda install it.

```
 conda install -c anaconda django
```

Comment: in virtual environment?

Comment: This should work in the terminal, not sure about a virtual environment.